# How to write in multiple database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, postgresql

I am trying to create a rails application which uses 2 different databases one postgresql as default and other mongodb i was able to connect both the databases to one rails application but now i am facing issue in accessing non default database througn my rails application controllers
Here is my database.yml configuration

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
development:
  <<: *default
  database: playpal_api_development
```

Here is my mongoid.yml configuration

```
development:
  
clients:
    default:
      database: chat_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

what i want to do is i want to update some data in both the databases how should i do it

```
auth = SecureRandom.uuid
guest = SecureRandom.uuid
@user_info.update(auth_token: auth, guest_token: guest)#this line updates to mypostgresql database
#what should be written here to update in mongodb database
```

Comment: You can't use Mongoid and ActiveRecord in the same class as the are tons of name clashes. For example both define `save`, `update`, etc. You would have to create two model classes (for example `User` and `Mongo::User`) and then manually CRUD both in something like a service object. At this point you should probally be questioning if its worth it.

Comment: Instead of including Mongoid, you could use the lower-level [MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) to insert / update the document(s) manually. See the [quick start tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/quick-start/)

Comment: @Stefan thanx for your suggestion it helped me to solve my query